# Binding knockout with tinymce

Tags: knockout.js, tinymce

I am trying to use `knockout 3.0.0` with `tinymce 4.0.18`.

I want to create something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/jY3X2/1/): few editable elements (3 here) but these elements are taken from knockout. Doing this without tinyMCE is not a problem (here is [my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/jY3X2/4/)).

But when I try to achieve the same [result with tinyMCE](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/jY3X2/5/) by doing something like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.editableAreas = ko.observableArray([{
        id : 1,
        txt: ko.observable('first text area'),
    },{
        id : 2,
        txt: ko.observable('second text area'),
    },{
        id : 3,
        txt: ko.observable('all observable text area'),
    }]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

tinymce.init({
    selector: "div.editableArea",
    schema: "html5",
    inline: true,
    toolbar: "bold italic underscore",
    menubar: false
});
```

Googling a little big I have found two custom bindings for tinyMCE ([first](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Bindings---tinyMCE) binding and [second](https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding)). Is this the best approach and how can I modify my fiddle to work as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a bindingHandler for binding DOM elements to the viewmodel is the "correct" way. Just include one of the bindingHandlers you linked to. I [updated your jsfiddle using the second bindingHandler](http://jsfiddle.net/jY3X2/6/) (chosen at random since I have no preference, since I don't know of any of them). After including that bindingHandler (and jquery and the jquery.tinymce.min.js which it seems dependent on) I updated the html to the following, in order to use the bindingHandler:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: editableAreas">
    <div class="editableArea" data-bind="wysiwyg: txt, wysiwygConfig: {    
        schema: 'html5',
        inline: true,
        toolbar: 'bold italic underscore',
        menubar: false
    } "></div>
</div>
```

In this case I have the tinymce configuration in the view. If you want to have it as a property in your viewModel it should be pretty easy to change it (for example with the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/jY3X2/7/))

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to move configuration in the viewModel, but I can not understand how can I do this easily. In fact I am failing to do this at all. I would be really thankful if you can show me how can I do it also.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jY3X2/7/) to have the options provided as a property on the viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks for referencing my work https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding.  Much appreciated.